# Deep link to another app then callback to the same browser

Tags: javascript, android, deep-linking

I have established deep link connection to the android app from mobile web browser now I want to redirect back specific URL to the same browser that the deep link came from. Currently the callback redirects always to the default browser.

Let's say I can identify the browser using the 
[navigator.userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)and pass it as parameter in deep ling to the app. What should be included in URI prefix for the Chrome, Firefox, Safari? To always open callback link in the same browser instead of device default one?

Also is it possible to open the same session instead of always the new tab?

Comment: I have same question too. Have you figured it out yet?